# Why isn't it possible to predict the gas costs for the following transaction?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm doing the ethernaut challenges right now. And regardless if my solution approach is correct or not, I would like to know why the following error occurs:

Inside of `main()` in `scripts/deploy.ts`:

```js
const KingHack = await ethers.getContractFactory("KingHack");
const contr = await KingHack.deploy();

await contr.deployed();
console.log("KingHack deployed to:", contr.address);

await contr.becomeKing("0x9447908B02681c71fD0f69dCa1424774ef446110", {value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01")})
console.log("transaction went through");
```

```
Uncaught:
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x9808503BAcDF58B3E2B7040A0A72A68B37360101","to":"0x28EFB80d4cD6175905DBa5D1453F2EC1AFC1dDFa","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x2386f26fc10000"},"data":"0xa64c9af00000000000000000000000009447908b02681c71fd0f69dca1424774ef446110","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.6.4)
    at step (/Users/throvn/Desktop/projects/ethernaut/King/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (/Users/throvn/Desktop/projects/ethernaut/King/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:590:20)
    at checkError (/Users/throvn/Desktop/projects/ethernaut/King/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:108:16)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/throvn/Desktop/projects/ethernaut/King/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:273:20)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/throvn/Desktop/projects/ethernaut/King/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:261:28) {
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  error: ProviderError: execution reverted
      at HttpProvider.request (/Users/throvn/Desktop/projects/ethernaut/King/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:74:19)
      at LocalAccountsProvider.request (/Users/throvn/Desktop/projects/ethernaut/King/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:188:34)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (/Users/throvn/Desktop/projects/ethernaut/King/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20),
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0x9808503BAcDF58B3E2B7040A0A72A68B37360101',
    to: '0x28EFB80d4cD6175905DBa5D1453F2EC1AFC1dDFa',
    value: BigNumber { value: "10000000000000000" },
    data: '0xa64c9af00000000000000000000000009447908b02681c71fd0f69dca1424774ef446110',
    accessList: null
  }
}
```

I can deploy the contract successfully (via hardhat) onto rinkeby.
My goal is to send `0.01 ether` to the contract which then sends the amount from their address to the `_kingGameAddress` contract.

```php
// ...
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract KingHack {

    function becomeKing(address payable _kingGameAddress) external payable {
        _kingGameAddress.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function destruct(address payable _kingGameAddress) external {
        selfdestruct(_kingGameAddress);
    }
}
```

### Update

It seems to be an issue with hardhat or my hardhat configuration, because on remix the transactions complete.

here is a link to the smartcontract I try to send the transfer to: https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x43BA674B4fbb8B157b7441C2187bCdD2cdF84FD5

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your contract and didn't get this error.

Maybe that your wallet doesn't have ether in it (empty).

Comment: Thanks for testing! I have enough ether in my wallet though :'(

Comment: Can you post more of the code the generates the transaction? (not just the one line)